# How to check the azure token (authentification) with the Laravel-Lumen framework

Tags: laravel, azure, laravel-5, lumen, azure-authentication

here is the architecture of my project:
I created an API with lumen and a front with the aurelia framework.
The front part communicates with the lumen API
Since my front Aurelia, I set up an authentication via a microsoft azure account. It works well, is it returns me well the data expected. The problem is that I want to set up a token check on the API side. I am therefore looking for a laravel package that allows me to communicate with the idP AZURE to check the token that the front is sending me back. Thank you

Comment: It looks like you're trying to validate the Access token from Azure in your Laurel/Aurelia back-end. This article goes over how to utilize the tymon/jwt-auth Laravel package in an Angular JS setting : https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs

You would be able to validate the signature for the JWT Token from the front end client using this library. Also Microsoft's docs explain how to validate the token. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens 
Does this answer it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to validate the Access token from Azure in your Laurel/Aurelia back-end.

This article goes over how to utilize the tymon/jwt-auth Laravel package in an Angular JS setting : https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs

Please refer to the Wiki for JWT-Auth for more self-help documentation in regards to using the library for JWT Signature validation : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki

And the docs for JWT-auth can be found here : https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

You can validate the signature for the JWT Token using this library.
Microsoft's docs explains further how to validate tokens from Azure Active Directory: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens